# How to delete hashtag in URL suffix

Tags: javascript, url, hashtag

How can I remove the hashtag which is used as a null link when triggering javascript?

What I mean is,
`<a href="#">link</a>` to trigger a javascript content, making the url http://whatever.com/index.html#.

How can I get rid of the # without removing it from the `<a>` attribute?

Comment: How is `addthis_config` used for anything that has something to do with urls?

Comment: What do you mean by "null link"? Where is your URL from that you want the hash portion removed?

Comment: Can you show us how the javascript content is triggered? Hint: `preventDefault()`

Comment: something like the dropdown in developer.android.com

Comment: use 'location.href' and cut out the # ?

Comment: you can read/set location.href, which represents you're url.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)">link</a>
```

Comment: Only problem is I can't find the location of it since it is embedded into a CMS

Comment: @RoyiNamir my understanding is OP wants an empty href content. Since the link is handled in JS.